# How do I use applescript to name a folder by pasting from the clipboard

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign, save-as

I work in graphic design and want to create an script for indesign that will automatically:

1. open a specified document template.
2. Create a new project folder.
3. Name that folder with text from the clipboard.
4. Save the newly opened document to the newly created folder and name that document with the same text from the clipboard.

I am very new to Applescript so type very slowly and use small words so that I can understand.

Here is what I have come up with in the way of code so far:

```as
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5"
set myDocument to open "cm:Graphic_Design:Design Studio Templates:Brochure_042012_001:Brochure_042012_001.indt"
end tell
tell application "Finder"
make new folder at folder "Work" of folder "Graphic_Design" of disk "cm" with properties {name:"untitled folder"}
set name of folder "untitled folder" of folder "Work" of folder "Graphic_Design" of disk "cm" to pbpaste
end tell
```

Comment: pbpaste is a shell command. If you wanted to run that you would 'do shell script "pbpaste"'. But as adayzdone shows in his code, applescript can get the clipboard directly without a shell command with something like 'set folderName to the clipboard'.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tell application "Finder" to set newFolder to make new folder at "cm:Graphic_Design:Work" with properties {name:(the clipboard as text)}
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS5"
    tell active document to save saving in (newFolder as text)
    end tell
```